# How to get objects in RemoteObjectModel

Tags: remote-objects

I have a VisualForce page and I am using the apex:remoteObjects component.

I am retrieving a custom object called Incident__c.

My code is:

```
  <apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Incident__c"
      jsShorthand="Incident"
      fields="Id,Name,CreatedDate,Number__c,CreatedBy.Name"/>
  </apex:remoteObjects>
```

However, my code fails because of the "CreatedBy.Name" part: `Invalid field 'Incident__c.CreatedBy.Name' specified. Ensure that you use the full API name for any custom fields.`

If I omit the "CreatedBy.Name" part, everything works but I am missing the data I need. How do I get the name of the user who created the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point the relationship queries are not supported in the remote objects .So you wont be able to traverse directly without having two queries .

An alternative would be to create a formula field at backend and query that instead .

In your case you can create a formula field like `CreatedBy.FirstName + ' ' +CreatedBy.LastName` and use that instead